# Posterior latent $t_p$-distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, gamma-distribution, posterior

I have a random vector $Y\in\Bbb{R}^p$ that is distributed as a multivariate t-distribution $t_p(\mu,\Sigma,\nu).$

> I know we can see the distribution as $$Y\; \vert\; Z=z \sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma /z)$$ with  $$Z\;\sim\; \Gamma(\frac{1}{2}\nu,\frac{1}{2}\nu).$$

I am reading the following result:

1. $$Z\vert Y=y\sim \Gamma(m_1,m_2)$$ with $m_1=\frac{1}{2}(\nu+p)$ et $m_2=\frac{1}{2}(\nu+(y-\mu)^T\Sigma(y-\mu)).$

> How can I prove the resultat ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use Bayes' rule.

You're assuming these:

1. $f_{Y|Z}(y \mid z) \propto z^{p/2}\det(\Sigma)^{-1/2} \exp\left[-\frac{z}{2}(y - \mu)^t\Sigma^{-1}(y-\mu) \right]$
2. $f_Z(z) \propto z^{\nu/2 - 1}\exp\left[-\frac{z\nu}{2}\right]$.

So 
\begin{align*}
f_{Z|Y}(z \mid y) &\propto f_{Y,Z}(y,z) \\
&\propto z^{p/2}\det(\Sigma)^{1/2} \exp\left[-\frac{z}{2}(y - \mu)^t\Sigma^{-1}(y-\mu) \right]z^{\nu/2 - 1}\exp\left[-\frac{z\nu}{2}\right]\\
&\propto z^{\frac{\nu + p}{2}-1}\exp\left[-\frac{z}{2}\left(\nu + (y - \mu)^t\Sigma^{-1}(y-\mu)  \right) \right].
\end{align*}